# Make a ProgressBar update smoothly

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm using a progress bar (in bar form). I wish to make the bar increase and decrease smoothly using an interpolator, but It's not working. This is what I have at the moment:

```
pb.setInterpolator(main.this, android.R.anim.bounce_interpolator);             
pb.setProgress(pb.getProgress()+10);
```

Am I doing something really wrong?

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get an error message or just a black screen?

Comment: [My Library Link](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/AnimateHorizontalProgressBar) Above link is my library.
Just use it if you want.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

The Interpolator has to be attached to an animation and this will work only on Honeycomb or higher:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
    // will update the "progress" propriety of seekbar until it reaches progress
    ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(seekbar, "progress", progress); 
    animation.setDuration(500); // 0.5 second
    animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    animation.start();
}
else 
    seekbar.setProgress(progress); // no animation on Gingerbread or lower
```

If your minimum SDK is Gingerbread or lower, add:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) 
// or 
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
```

to your function/class.

I used a DecelerateInterpolator, but this is optional and there are others possibilities.

Comment: @HamidrezaHosseinkhani - try `animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());`

Comment: Would like to add something, if you want it to move from point x to point y, just put: ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(seekbar, "progress", now, end); Also, if it isnt smooth, try new LinearInterpolator()

Comment: Be aware that user can have different system animator scale value and setDuration will not be real time accurate.

Answer (score 18):

Here is a self-contained drop in solution:

```
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class AnimatingProgressBar extends ProgressBar {

    private static final Interpolator DEFAULT_INTERPOLATER = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();

    private ValueAnimator animator;
    private ValueAnimator animatorSecondary;
    private boolean animate = true;

    public AnimatingProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public AnimatingProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AnimatingProgressBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public boolean isAnimate() {
        return animate;
    }

    public void setAnimate(boolean animate) {
        this.animate = animate;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void setProgress(int progress) {
        if (!animate) {
            super.setProgress(progress);
            return;
        }
        if (animator != null)
            animator.cancel();
        if (animator == null) {
            animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(getProgress(), progress);
            animator.setInterpolator(DEFAULT_INTERPOLATER);
            animator.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    AnimatingProgressBar.super.setProgress((Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue());
                }
            });
        } else
            animator.setIntValues(getProgress(), progress);
        animator.start();

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void setSecondaryProgress(int secondaryProgress) {
        if (!animate) {
            super.setSecondaryProgress(secondaryProgress);
            return;
        }
        if (animatorSecondary != null)
            animatorSecondary.cancel();
        if (animatorSecondary == null) {
            animatorSecondary = ValueAnimator.ofInt(getProgress(), secondaryProgress);
            animatorSecondary.setInterpolator(DEFAULT_INTERPOLATER);
            animatorSecondary.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    AnimatingProgressBar.super.setSecondaryProgress((Integer) animation
                            .getAnimatedValue());
                }
            });
        } else
            animatorSecondary.setIntValues(getProgress(), secondaryProgress);
        animatorSecondary.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        if (animator != null)
            animator.cancel();
        if (animatorSecondary != null)
            animatorSecondary.cancel();
    }

}
```

replace `ProgressBar` with `AnimatingProgressBar` in your layout

You many also change the type to AnimatingProgressBar to utilize `setAnimate()` to disable animation (could be useful when restoring activity state)

Comment: Beautiful. Note, however, that this requires minSdkVersion of 11.

Comment: I hope that anything < sdk 11 would disappear; supporting old versions of Android is like supporting IE6

Comment: nice, just a small fix in the setSecondaryProgress :
animatorSecondary = ValueAnimator.ofInt(getSecondaryProgress(), secondaryProgress);
          animatorSecondary.setIntValues(getSecondaryProgress(), secondaryProgress);

Comment: This answer works like a charm as it reset the progress bar progress with reverse animation which is the problem I'm facing in a recyclerView.

Answer (score 13):

If you change progress value each time by 1 (for example from 45 to 46) you'll not see animation. Better to change progress by 100 points, for this you just need to multiply your max value to 100 and each progress value to 100 too. For example:

```
private void setProgressMax(ProgressBar pb, int max) {
    pb.setMax(max * 100);
}

private void setProgressAnimate(ProgressBar pb, int progressTo) 
{
    ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(pb, "progress", pb.getProgress(), progressTo * 100);
    animation.setDuration(500);
    animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    animation.start();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I worked out how to do it, by using a runnable I was able to update the progress bar several times a second and so give the sliding effect. The code is below:

```
private Runnable SmoothIncrement = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           final long start = mStartTime;
           long millis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;

           if(track!=increase) {
               if((pb.getProgress()==100)&&(count<target)) {
                   pb.setProgress(0);
               }
               pb.incrementProgressBy(1);
               track++;
               incrementor.postAtTime(this, start + millis);
           }
           else {
               incrementor.removeCallbacks(this);
           }
       }
    };
```

Here, 'track' keeps track of how many increments have been done, and increase is the total number of increments that should be done. I can dynamically increase the number of increments from the UI thread to give a smooth effect. The code only works for progress bars that won't need to decrease.

To run it, simply use this code:

```
                    mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    incrementor.removeCallbacks(SmoothIncrement);
                    if(track!=0) {
                        track -= increase;
                    }
                    incrementor.postDelayed(SmoothIncrement, 0);
```

Comment: Can you tell me what type of object is `incrementor` and how this is applied to a ProgressBar. I am also looking for this solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but please check it:

```
pb.setProgress(pb.getProgress() * 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation interpolator applies to indeterminate progress.
Since you set progress I think you intend to use regular one with values. 
I think the best for you would be to increase maximum value of progress and 
go in smaller increments.