# How to show a Horizontal Android Indeterminate Progress Bar

Tags: android, android-progressbar

How to show an indeterminate horizontal progress bar in android? The animation of the progress bar should start from 0 to 100 and then go back from 100 to 0 continuously. I am not looking for the wheel progress bar.

Comment: I would disagree: question is about programming, so what's the problem? Can't really understand downgrading reason

Comment: I have posted an example implementation of this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097795/android-make-a-progress-bar-update-smoothly

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I already knew that `setIndeterminate` will give an infinite horizontal progress bar. But it will be similar to the loading wheel, except that it will be horizontal. If you see my question I was looking for horizontal bar which starts from 0 and goes all the way to 100 (a gradual increase). If you want to achieve this in Android, you must use your progress bar as below:

```
 <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_horizontal"
    android:indeterminateOnly="false"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_horizontal"
    android:minHeight="24dip"
    android:maxHeight="24dip" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

As I wanted to change the background of my progress bar, I changed the ProgressDrawable and IndeterminateDrawable. The original drawables are located under `frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable`. Copy them to your project and change the color according to your needs.

Create a thread which updates the progress count and does a `Thread.Sleep`. Then it sends the message to the Handler which will update the progress bar in UI thread.

Comment: You only need to add these **2 lines** to your *ProgressBar*
`android:indeterminate="true"` and  `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"`

Answer (score 16):

Use the method setIndeterminate of ProgressBar:

```
android.widget.ProgressBar bar = new android.widget.ProgressBar(context);
bar.setIndeterminate(true);
```

But yeah, you could have found this pretty quickly in the developer docs.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setIndeterminate%28boolean%29

Answer (score 14):

Maybe a bit late, but you can do something like this:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" />
```

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 10):

To expand on Vinoth Answer, here is a ready code:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarLoadingRecite"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@android:drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal"
        android:minHeight="24dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:maxHeight="24dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

In the xml defining your progress bar, you can add

```
style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
```