# Indeterminate progress in Android Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to replicate the experience found when you are uninstalling an app in ICS. Specifically the indeterminate progress indicator under the title bar. I have tried using `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS)` and the various methods on `Activity` but to no avail. It instead shows a spinning progress bar in the top right hand corner of the screen/title bar. Am I missing something simple here? Or is this completely custom?

Here is the code I am using:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
}
```

[image: Uninstall Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried using the `indeterminate` attributes on your `ProgressBar`? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449345/android-indeterminate-progress-bar and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

Comment: Show the code you are using.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using the `ActionBar` indeterminate progress bar, but you are looking for a [`ProgressBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) View.

You can create the `View` programmatically or add it to a layout file like --

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true" />
```

Typically, you can decide when it is shown by calling `.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` to show and `.setVisibility(View.GONE)` when you are done.

If you have a minimum API of 11 and set your activity or app theme to `@android:style/Theme.Holo` you will get exactly that `ProgressBar` shown in your image.

If you want a similar effect on pre-API 11 devices, check out [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere)

Comment: HoloEverywhere looks like it has moved to here: https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere

Answer (score 4):

*Disclaimer: @iagreen's answer is still the right one -- to get layout similar to the one in uninstall activity your best option is to just use it in a layout, not rely on window* features)

But you were on a right track with windows features, you just mixed two of them up.

See, this:

```
setProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
```

requests the window's *[horizontal] progress bar* to be indeterminate. And this:

```
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

shows the window's *indeterminate progress bar* -- thing is, it's a completely diffrerent view.

To clarify things further, this gets you a **horizontal indeterminate progress bar** shown at the top of the window

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
setProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
setProgressBarVisibility(true);
```

and this gets you a **spinner-style progress bar** in the actionbar

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a horizontal progress bar in the image, the Action Bar indeterminate progress bar is a Spinner style. You'd either need to make a custom view for the action bar, or put it as a view in your main layout. You can hide the action bar and make a custom header for a particular activity. Just use the Spinner style indeterminate progress bar, it's what everyone expects to see in the Action Bar.