# entity.getContentLength() == -1

Tags: android

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(get, localContext);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
long totalLength = entity.getContentLength();
```

why the totalLength is -1? I am sure the content is not null;

Answer (score 1):

That's because the content length is not known, as [the docs](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContentLength%28%29) mention.

> Tells the length of the content, if known.
>
> **Returns:**
> the number of bytes of the content, or a negative number if unknown. If the content length is known but exceeds `Long.MAX_VALUE`, a negative number is returned.

**When is the Content-Length header missing?**
The [HTTP specifications](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4) does allow the `Content-Length` to be missing if, for example, the `Transfer-Encoding` field is set. That is another way to check the length of the message.

**How to show the download progress?**
You should keep in mind that you cannot always determine the content length beforehand.
One thing you can do, is showing an indeterminate progress bar, like this:

[image: Image with indeterminate progress]

It shows the user the progress, but indicates that the progress value is indeterminate.

How to do so, see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449345/android-indeterminate-progress-bar).

Comment: understand, But if I want to update the download progress, what should I do?

Comment: I believe that the server does not included the content length header. and it can be done on the server. Is that right @MCEmperor?

Comment: @gdestiny That's correct. The server does not always include the `Content-Length` header.