# ProgressBar Animation

Tags: android, animation, progress-bar

I want to use different animations in one ProgressBar. Code for init and set animation:

```
progressBar = (ProgressBar) this.view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.anim.progress_small));
```

When I want only this code, everything is working well, but when I set new animation by

```
 `progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.anim.progress_small))`
```

it doesn't work.
How to use one ProgressBar for more animation?`

Answer (score 1):

You are retrieving an animation from the resources with `getDrawable()`.

I may be mistaken, but I don't think there is a way to 'animate' progress changes in a progress bar other than changing the progress very quickly in steps to your desired value. I wrote some sample code for a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097795/android-make-a-progress-bar-update-smoothly).

Answer (score 0):

```
progress.setProgressDrawable(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.graph_blue_green));
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progress, "progress", 0, 5000);
anim.setDuration(1000);
anim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
anim.start();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.