# Create smooth indeterminate horizontal progress bar

Tags: android, view, progress-bar

I want use smooth indeterminate horizontal progress bar like gmail or FB app. I want support api level 8+. I searched and i see a library but i want write this code not use lib. I find some question and answer about this but i cant understand and use this. I read this ([Make a ProgressBar update smoothly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097795/android-make-a-progress-bar-update-smoothly)), in accept answer what is incrementor and count? in last answer, how can i use this class and methods? please explain about use this class or method in program? Thanks and sorry for my stupid question :)

Comment: Nobody know answer my question?! Please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a [Blog Post](http://antoine-merle.com/blog/2013/11/12/make-your-progressbar-more-smooth/) about this a few months ago.

You can find the whole implementation [HERE](https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar/blob/master/library/src/main/java/fr/castorflex/android/smoothprogressbar/SmoothProgressBar.java)

if you want to reproduce exactly the gmail's progressbar, [here is the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/UnifiedEmail/+/kitkat-release/src/com/android/mail/ui/ButteryProgressBar.java)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I want to ask you in your gmail progressbar source code. The class must `extends View` ? coz my main.java was already `extends ActionBarActivity`

Comment: What's different between yours and third link?! (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/UnifiedEmail/+/kitkat-release/src/com/android/mail/ui/ButteryProgressBar.java)

Comment: @Mr.Hyde here is a gif https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar and here is a demo https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.castorflex.android.smoothprogressbar.sample

Comment: @CFlex Does it work on ProgressDialog too? I mean set SmoothProgressDrawable as IndeterminaterDrawable. In fact, how to show smooth horizontal progress in dialog?

Comment: @Mr.Hyde Can't see any reason why it wouldn't work. What have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a View to do that from google (**LinearProgressIndicator**).
you can custom colors and height.
I explained it in this post :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68505259/2719243