# How to fill progress bar smoothly with animation

Tags: java, android, animation

I have implemented the progress bar with fill animation, but I would like to have a animation effect like a train and which would fill fast to a particular point and then a bit slow brake in the speed till the end point. My current animation implementation is:

```
ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(pbOption, "progress", percent);
animation.setDuration(1250);
animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
animation.start();
```

Comment: It sounds like you'd rather want a `DecelerateInterpolator`.

Comment: **`ObjectAnimator progressAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(pbOption, "progress", 10000, 0);`**

Comment: you need to implement custom interpolator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a ProgressBar update smoothly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097795/make-a-progressbar-update-smoothly)

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=fill+progress+bar+smoothly+with+animation+site:stackoverflow.com&client=ubuntu&hs=fBD&channel=fs&dcr=0&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIt-yarZHaAhWMMo8KHfi2AvwQrQIIMygEMAA&biw=1600&bih=727

Comment: purpose of this question is about the progress bar animation not about smoothness since i have already achieved that @NileshRathod

Comment: ObjectAnimator progressAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(pbOption, "progress", 10000, 0); this shows "progress" parameter has some error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change AccelerateInterpolator() to DecelerateInterpolator().
Here the rate of change starts out quickly and and then decelerates.

```
   ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(pbOption, "progress", percent);
            animation.setDuration(1250);
            animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            animation.start();
```

Comment: AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator() did it better!

Comment: I want the complete code with progress bar to integrate. kindly provide

Answer (score 3):

A super cute way of doing it on kotlin. based on @ajay-j-g 's answer

```
fun ProgressBar.smoothProgress(percent: Int){
    val animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "progress", percent)
    animation.duration = 400
    animation.interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
    animation.start()
}

progressbar.smoothProgress(80)
```